# retrieve value from QlineEdit inside QtableWidget in Pyqt4 Python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qlineedit

I am having trouble in Retrieving the Entered in QWidgetlineEdit box.
Got C++ Implementation of the Same but unable to retrieve using Python,

```
    self.line = QtGui.QLineEdit() 
    i =0
    while(i<self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
    self.q = (QtGui.QLineEdit()).self.tableWidget.cellWidget(i, 1)
    j = self.line.text()
    print j
    i +=1
```

working code in c++:

---

```
QLineEdit* tmpLineEdit;
QString tmpString;
for(int row=0; row < moneyTableWidget.rowCount(); row++)
{
    tmpLineEdit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(moneyTableWidget.cellWidget(row,1));
    tmpString = tmpLineEdit->text();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the code that you provide with C ++ is dangerous since nobody guarantees that the cellWidget that is returned is a QLineEdit so a verification improves the code:

```
QString tmpString;
for(int row=0; row < moneyTableWidget.rowCount(); row++)
{
    if(QLineEdit * tmpLineEdit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit *>(moneyTableWidget.cellWidget(row,1)))
        tmpString = tmpLineEdit->text();
}
```

In the case of python it is not necessary to do a casting but you have to verify that the widget that returns cellWidget is a QLineEdit using `isinstance()`:

```
tmpString = ""
for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
    widget = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 1)
    if isinstance(widget, QtGui.QLineEdit):
        tmpString = widget.text()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your Support, I was struggling with this issue since 3 days.
The solution given by you is working like a charm!!
 
updated working code :

tmpString = ""
for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
    widget = self.tableWidget.cellWidget(row, 1)
    if isinstance(widget, QtGui.QCheckBox):
        tmpString = widget.isChecked()
        print tmpString
    elif isinstance(widget, QtGui.QLineEdit):
        tmpString = widget.text()
        print tmpString